# Retaining "this" inside callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

I'm not sure if this question is specific to Backbone.js.  I have a model with the following render function:

```
render: function() { 
    var self = this;
    this.$el.empty();
    this.model.fetch({
        success: function() {
            self.$el.append(self.template(self.model.attributes));      
        }
    });

    return this;
}
```

As you can see, inside the `success` callback function, I use a variable called `self`.  This is because inside the callback, `this` is set to `window` when I want it to be set to the view. Is there a way I can retain the original reference of `this` without storing it in another variable?

Comment: For small callbacks without inner callbacks you can use function.prototype.bind (or similar alternatives) but for larger chunks of code I recommend sticking with "self" or "that" because these lexically scoped variables continue to work even for nested callbacks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way I can retain the original reference of this without storing it in another variable?

Yes, this is a reasonable use case for the [`proxy` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

```
this.model.fetch({
    success: $.proxy(function() {
        this.$el.append(this.template(this.model.attributes));      
    }, this)
});
```

---

Alternatively you can use underscore's [`bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) method:

```
this.model.fetch({
    success: _.bind(function() {
        this.$el.append(this.template(this.model.attributes));      
    }, this)
});
```

Comment: with $.proxy you don't need self anymore. use this in the success callback.

Comment: And `self` is a terrible name for such things due to the presence of `window.self`.

Comment: @muistooshort, actually `self` is a very good choice. It's common, and descriptive. Just because window has a default property `self` doesn't mean that you shouldn't use `self` in other scopes.

Comment: And a simple missing `var self = this` leads to confusing errors that can easily be avoided by using a different name.

Comment: @muistooshort, `"use strict"` and you'll never run into that issue.

Comment: I think the best way is to follow underscore practice and use `bind`

Comment: @VitaliyPetrychuk, feel free to add your own answer.

Answer (score 6):

Use the [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function to bind your object to the `this` variable within a function.

```
render: function() { 
    this.$el.empty();
    var successFunc = function() { 
                 this.$el.append(this.template(this.model.attributes));      
    };

    this.model.fetch({
        success: successFunc.bind(this)
        }
    });

    return this;
}
```

Comment: `bind` is not backwards compatible, `$.proxy` is.

Comment: Good point. I'll leave my answer for those developers not using jQuery. Note that the implementation of `bind` is simple enough and provided at the MDN link, if you don't want to use a library which provides it.

Comment: @zzzzBov: But `_.bind` would be more idiomatic in a Backbone app.

Comment: @muistooshort, I would say that `_.bind` and `$.proxy` are equally idiomatic. It really depends on whether you're coming from the underscore world or whether you're coming from the jQuery world. I tend to prefer `$.proxy` due to how event bindings are handled, but a call to [bindAll](http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll) can be very convenient as part of class initialization.

Comment: Wish I could give both of you guys best answer.  This was a very thorough explanation/discussion and I have a much better understanding of how to use bind now.

Comment: It's backbone - jQuery (or even Zepto) is required, so $.proxy is available.